Was Arthur Fleck sexually assaulted by the prison guards in "Joker: Folie à Deux"?
In Joker: Folie à Deux (2024), Arthur Fleck represents himself at his trial. Wearing his Joker makeup and suit, he delivers an impassioned speech about feeling liberated as the Joker and refusing to let his tormentors keep him down. During this rant, he also insults the Arkham Asylum guards.
After the court session, Arthur is returned to Arkham. The guards, including Jackie Sullivan, are enraged by his courtroom insults. They drag him to the prison bathroom, where they forcibly wash off his Joker makeup. They then force him into the showers, pushing him down. The scene cuts away, and we next see Arthur being brought back to his cell, barely conscious. He's still wearing his Joker costume but is now without pants, clad only in underwear below the waist.
This incident seems to have a profound impact on Arthur's behavior. In the final court session, during closing statements, Arthur unexpectedly renounces his Joker persona. He confesses to feeling sad and tired of life, which causes his followers, including Lee, to abandon him and leave the courthouse in disappointment.
Given the implied violence, Arthur's partial undress, the sudden scene cut, and Arthur's state upon returning to his cell, the sequence strongly hints at a traumatic event. I'm wondering if it was meant to imply that the prison guards raped Arthur in the showers.
